# Is it possible to restrict third party app access on iOS

Tags: ios

There's an app i want to get built but not sure if one of the main features is even possible. I want to be able to use an iOS app to restrict access to other third party apps (mostly games) on a device.

The app would detect which apps are on the device & then user could choose which apps would be blocked.

I'm assuming this requires some operating system level access which is why I think it cannot be done but would be very happy to be proven otherwise.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: App Store approved iOS apps can't do what you want.

Comment: The iOS apps are sandboxed, there's no way you can generalize that in a way that you could implement this feature to check all the other installed apps that user has.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Parental Control Restrictions, built into iOS, may be able to do some of what you're looking for.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304

[image: iOS Restrictions]